# To test the convergence of $\int_0^{1} \frac{x^p \log x}{1+ x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

To test the convergence of the improper integral:

$$\int_0^{1} \frac{x^p \log x}{1+ x^2} dx$$

Here we see that $0$  is the point of infinite discontinuty  for  $p<0$.

Let $f(x) = \frac{x^p \log x}{1+ x^2}$ and $g(x) = x^p$.

Now as we take..

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log x}{1+ x^2}$$

Will this $g(x)$ work? Not getting clue to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may observe that
$$
\frac{x^p \log x}{1+ x^2} \sim x^p \log x, \quad \quad x \to 0^+.
$$ The integral
$$
\int_0^1x^p \log x \: dx
$$ is convergent if and only if $p>-1$, with (using integration by parts) the value
$$
\int_0^1x^p \log x \: dx =-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}, \quad \quad p>-1.
$$ 
Then $$
\int_0^1\frac{x^p \log x}{1+ x^2} \:dx
$$ is **convergent if and only if** $p>-1$.